# If values in cells in header row fall in between start/end dates, then range in offset cells below get a fill color selected by the user

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, border, conditional-formatting

I have managed to get a few lines together, but since I am new to VBA, and since I need 95 more rows, my code is ridiculously long. I really do need help to shorten it. My real challenges, though, are these:

1. I want the workbook to be refreshed when I change any fill color in column B. (Excel does not seem to register a color change as a change.)
2. If a date on row 2 (which holds dates for 366 days, not
   necessary starting with January 1st) is the first day of the month,
   then I want a black left border in the same column from row 4 to row
   103. Example: If L2 is February 1 2022, then range L4:L103 has a left black border. I know I can do this with conditional formatting,
   but then I have to use the same conditional format in 366 columns,
   which makes my workbook quite heavy.

For a visualization, see this image:

[image: For a visualization]

My stone age code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

Set r1 = Range("G4:NF4")
Set r2 = Range("G5:NF5")
Set r3 = Range("G6:NF6")
```

etc... and then...

```
For Each c In r1
    If c.Offset(-2, 0).Value >= Range("E4").Value And c.Offset(-2, 0).Value <= Range("F4") Then
    If Range("B4").Interior.Color < 0 Then
    c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Else
        c.Interior.Color = Range("B4").Interior.Color
    Else
        c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
Next c

For Each c In r2
    If c.Offset(-3, 0).Value >= Range("E5").Value And c.Offset(-3, 0).Value <= Range("F5") Then
    If Range("B5").Interior.Color < 0 Then
    c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Else
        c.Interior.Color = Range("B5").Interior.Color
    Else
        c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
Next c

For Each c In r3
    If c.Offset(-4, 0).Value >= Range("E6").Value And c.Offset(-4, 0).Value <= Range("F6") Then
    If Range("B6").Interior.Color < 0 Then
    c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Else
        c.Interior.Color = Range("B6").Interior.Color
    Else
        c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
Next c
```

etc...

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Correct, the `Worksheet.Change` event does not fire on formatting changes. I'm not sure if there's a reliable alternative either, tbh. Maybe you could use the `Worksheet.SelectionChange` event but again, I doubt it'll be reliable.

Comment: Maybe I could use a dropdown list for color changes. That would count as a change, right?

Comment: Yes, then the `Worksheet.Change` event should work.

Comment: Okay, so that part is solved then, thanks! "Only" help to shorten the code and challenge #2 left. :)

Comment: [`Day`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/day-function) function.